# Access directive prop in another part of the view

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am using an autocomplete-directive and would like to toggle a bool if no option matches the users input.

Here is a directive similar to the one I am using:

```
angular.module('MyModule', []).directive('autoComplete', function($timeout) {
    return function(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
            iElement.autocomplete({
                source: scope[iAttrs.uiItems],
                select: function() {
                    $timeout(function() {
                      iElement.trigger('input');
                    }, 0);
                }
            });
    };
});
```

A controller with some names and (if needed) a bool.
I say "if needed" thinking that it might be enough to have to bool in the view and maybe not needed in the controller?

```
function DefaultCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.names = ["john", "bill", "charlie", "robert", "alban", "oscar", "marie", "celine", "brad", "drew", "rebecca", "michel", "francis", "jean", "paul", "pierre", "nicolas", "alfred", "gerard", "louis", "albert", "edouard", "benoit", "guillaume", "nicolas", "joseph"];

  $scope.noMatch = true;

}
```

And the view:

```
<div ng-app='MyModule'>
    <div ng-controller='DefaultCtrl'>
    <div ng-show="noMatch">
          NoMacth
        </div>
        <input auto-complete ui-items="names" ng-model="selected">

    </div>
</div>
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cyjujo3a/1/)

I have tried to get a hold of the directives property by doing things like:

```
{{ auto-complete }}
```

in the view, hoping that it would display something but it only renders a 0.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you just asking how to set a scope variable from inside your directive's link function?

Comment: If it solves my problem then I guess i am :)
Im thinking there must be a way to check if the list is active or not and then toggle the bool based on it.

Comment: You said the directive you posted is *similar* to the one you're using so I wasn't sure exactly what you're asking. You have access to the scope (it's passed in on the link function) so you could just use regular ol' dot notation to access the scope variables. This will likely cause issues if you are trying to use more than one of these auto-complete directives on a view.

Comment: Sorry if I was un-clear. If I understand you correctly I can access the directives scope in the view. So its in the directive i need a function that tells med wheter I have a match or not and then toggle the bool from within the directive? Im gonna try to read up on directives. Its a bit confusing. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If your directive does not use isolate scope, then it's scope is already the parent controller's scope, and any methods and properties the directive places in scope will be accessible throughout the view as if they were part of the normal parent controller scope, because they are.

The directive you referenced does not appear to use scope, so it hasn't placed any values to reference.

Here is an example. If you use a directive like this, then `someProperty` would be accessible in the parent controller scope anywhere in the view as a normal `{{someProperty}}`

```
angular.module('app.directives.myDirective', [
  'myService'
]).directive('myDirective', function (myService) {
  return {
    restrict: 'AE', // my personal preference
    templateUrl: 'directives/myDirectiveView.html', // optional
    link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {
      $scope.someProperty = 'true';
    }
  };
});
```